# Paginate results from a multi variable query mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a mysql database and use a multi variable search page, find.php, to input variables. The results come out correctly (count is correct and so is page 1 of the results) but when I try and go to the next page I get an error :: Undefined index: term1 line 60 ::Undefined index: term2 line 61 and so on.
Search2.php is as set below:

```
<?php

include "db.inc.php";

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 15;

$term1 = $_POST['term1'];
$term2 = $_POST['term2'];
$term3 = $_POST['term3'];
$term4 = $_POST['term4'];

$sql ="SELECT * FROM cdrequests WHERE pname  LIKE '%$term1%' AND date LIKE '%$term2%' AND date LIKE '%$term3%' AND dept LIKE '%$term4%' LIMIT $start_from, 15";


$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cdrequests WHERE pname  LIKE '%$term1%' AND date LIKE '%$term2%' AND date LIKE '%$term3%' AND dept LIKE '%$term4%'"); 
$number=mysql_num_rows($query); 
print "<font size=\"5\" color=white><b>CD Requests</b></font> </P>";
?>
```

pagination structure

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM cdrequests WHERE pname  LIKE '%$term1%' AND date LIKE '%$term2%' AND date LIKE '%$term3%' AND dept LIKE '%$term4%'";  
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 15);


/******  build the pagination links ******/
// range of num links to show
$range = 3;



// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($page > 1) {
   // show << link to go back to page 1
   echo " <a href='search2.php?page=1'><b>First</b></a> ";
   // get previous page num
   $prev = $page - 1;
   // show < link to go back to 1 page
   echo " <a href='search2.php?page=$prev'><b>&laquo;</b></a> ";
} // end if 



// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $page) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " <font  size='5' color=yellow><b> $x </b></font> ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo " <a href='search2.php?page=$x'>$x</a> ";
      } // end else
   } // end if 
} // end for


// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($page != $total_pages) {
   // get next page
   $next = $page + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
   echo " <a href='search2.php?page=$next'><b>&raquo;</b></a> ";
   // echo forward link for lastpage
   echo " <a href='search2.php?page=$total_pages'><b>Last</b></a> ";
} // end if
/****** end build pagination links ******/

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Somehow going to page 2 fails to carry over proper info of variable term 1, term2 etc.
Any idea/help appreciated

Comment: www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Your page links do not pass `term1`, `term2`, etc. back to the server. Also if you are going to pass them in the link then you need to check `$_REQUEST['term1']`, `$_REQUEST['term2']`, etc. to cover both GET and POST requests.

The code of the links should be like this:

```
echo " <a href='search2.php?page=$next".
    "&amp;term1=".urlencode($term1).
    "&amp;term2=".urlencode($term2).
    "&amp;term3=".urlencode($term3).
    "&amp;term4=".urlencode($term4)"'><b>&raquo;</b></a> ";
```

If you have too many parameters to pass to the server then you should probably consider sending POST requests when clicking on the links using JavaScript.

Comment: makes sense, so being the noob I am, where would I insert the $_REQUEST['term1'] etc? thanks

Comment: Start with :::   $term1=$_REQUEST['term'] instead

Comment: thanks, so how do I implement this section in my code to ensure passing of the terms?  :::: "you need to check $_REQUEST['term1'], $_REQUEST['term2'], etc"

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: term1 , still getting this message, doesn't seem to work, all I did was change the link code as you suggested above, I didn't change anything else...still getting the Undefined index error.

Comment: So I need to save the session variable, session_start() , seems like the best way to do it, any tips on this?